# Where is the explanation of what "community wiki" is?

Tags: support, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

1. Every question I ask offers me the chance to designate it "community wiki". I do not because I don't know what "community wiki" is.
2. I see that there is *lots* of discussion on whether "community wiki" should exist, and if so, how to use it properly. I do not want to get into that discussion.

I *would* like to know what the official (if hotly argued) explanation of "commmunity wiki" is. Is there a link to it somewhere?

Comment: Here is the [Community Wiki FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).  When looking for overviews like this try searching MSO with `[faq]` as a search term :)

Answer (score 4):

As with many things in SO, the mouseover tooltip explains...

[image]

> Community owned posts do not generate any reputation for the owner, have a lower reputation barrier for collaborative editing, and show only a revision history instead of a signature block.

Comment: That gives me 3 rules about, or attributes of community-owned posts. I can infer that the union of all community-owned posts is the community wiki. But that does not explain what the community wiki is -- what its originally declared purpose was or is.