# What are "Community Wiki" posts?

Tags: support, faq, community-wiki

Some questions and answers are marked *Community Wiki* and are owned by a *community wiki* user:

[image: image showing the "owner" of a CW post is "community wiki"]

(In fact, this very question is one of them)

- Why have *Community Wiki* posts?
- How do *Community Wiki* posts work?
- How does a post become a *Community Wiki* post?
- How can the *Community Wiki* status be removed from a post?
- How can I find *Community Wiki* posts?

[Return to FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)

Comment: I searched for **What are “Community Wiki” posts?** and finally reached its answer which is also posted by a **community wiki**.

Comment: I just posted a question can I see example of a community wiki post, because it doesn't really say anywhere clearly "THIS IS A COMMUNITY WIKI POST". This subtle hint on the right bottom of post in pilot-vision font was not enough for me.

Comment: The first thought that came to mind when I saw this is, "It better be by the community wiki..."

Comment: As it is said in @community robot's profile page, it “own[s] community questions and answers **_so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them_**.” See https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Answer (score 685):

### Why have Community Wiki posts?

One of the goals of the website is to be a continually evolving source of good information. Community Wiki posts help enhance the *wiki* aspect of the site.

For more information about the proper use of community wiki, see [The Future of Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

### How do Community Wiki posts work?

Community Wiki posts work by partly transferring ownership of the post from the original author to the community.  They make the post easier to edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but they do not contribute to any user's reputation.

Some of the key features are:

- A much lower reputation (**100** instead of **2000**) is needed to freely edit a community wiki post originally made by someone else. <sup>1</sup>
- Voting on a community wiki post does not affect the author's reputation, and downvoting a community wiki answer will not deduct 1 reputation from the voter.
- Accepting an answer marked as community wiki [does not affect its original author's reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145935/152859), and [does not give +2 to the question author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297464/152859).
- Bounties awarded to answer marked as community wiki still give reputation to the original author.
- Edits suggested by users with less than 100 reputation will still provide +2 reputation to the editor when approved.
- The original author still gets badges based on community posts.
- The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.
- The original author still receives notifications for substantial edits, suggested edits, and comments on the post.
- The user listed in the author box need not be the original author. Rather, it is the user with the [highest percentage of authorship](http://blog.codinghorror.com/mixing-oil-and-water-authorship-in-a-wiki-world/) in the final revision, determined by the number of lines inserted or deleted, with a bonus (factor of 2) for the original author. Note that the name shown is [calculated upon each edit and cached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/old-usernames-stick-to-community-wiki-posts), so if the user later changes their display name, their previous name will still be displayed until the post is edited again.

### How does a post become a Community Wiki post?

There are only three ways that a post becomes community wiki.

- The **answer**'s (not question's) author checks the *community wiki* checkbox when composing or editing the answer. Note that this checkbox isn't available to users with less than 10 reputation. The checkbox also is not available if the question being answered is already a community wiki. <sup>2</sup>
- If you post an answer to a community wiki question, your answer will also be community wiki.
- A moderator has reason to believe that the question or answer serves better in community wiki mode - if you believe your post [should be converted](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) to a community wiki, you may [flag it for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183).

In the past, questions could be made community wiki by their authors or by certain automatic triggers but [now the only means is by a moderator converting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940) to community wiki. When a moderator converts a question to community wiki, all existing answers will also be converted in addition to converting future answers.<sup>3</sup>

### How can the Community Wiki status be removed from a post?

[Community Wiki status can only be removed by a moderator.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373)

If community wiki status is removed from a post, [reputation is automatically recalculated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233945/165773) as if the post was never a wiki.

### How can I find Community Wiki posts?

To search for Community Wiki posts, type `wiki:1`, `wiki:yes`, or `wiki:true` into the search box. See [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for more information.

### Miscellaneous

- Rollbacks cannot remove community wiki status.
- The Community User<sup>4</sup> might appear as the last editor of a post, even a non-wiki post. This happens either 1. when an edit by an anonymous user is approved, or 2. when it randomly pokes old unanswered questions so they get some attention. In the latter case, this will only be shown in certain overviews and on a notice on the question, and not an actual revision in the revision history.
- If you are looking for an example community wiki post, see this question and this answer. They are all community wikis. You can easily identify community wikis by the text "community wiki" where the author's profile picture should be.

---

<sup>1</sup> The original author of a community wiki post can *always* edit it, even if they have <100 reputation. Other edits made by users with less than 100 reputation must be reviewed in the usual way before being applied.

<sup>2</sup> Since [October 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67582/152859), there is no *community wiki* checkbox when asking a question.

<sup>3</sup> In the past, converting a question to community wiki would not automatically convert the answers, so you may see non-Community Wiki answers to older Community Wiki questions. Additionally, if a non-Community Wiki question is [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question) into a Community Wiki question, the imported answers will not be automatically converted. If you would like to edit them, you can flag for a moderator to add Community Wiki status to the answer. (Newer answers to these older questions will automatically be Community Wiki.)

<sup>4</sup> See [Who is the Community User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user), or read the [Community User’s profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

Comment: So basically the only benefit is to enable users with a low reputation to edit the post? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @GôTô I think there's more. I don't do substantial edits to other users' answers. I do formatting, grammar fixes etc., but hardly ever expand their answers. My reasoning: their answer, their reputation, their job. I may write a comment ("And what about…?") and hope the author of the answer will improve it; or I leave my separate answer (e.g. "The alternative way to do it is…"). When the answer is Community Wiki then I read it "don't add your answer, improve me instead". The benefit is usually one comprehensive answer instead of many concurrent, competing, sometimes partial ones.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski interesting how a simple label changes the way you see it. I understand, although I personally don't share this approach. Thank you for sharing this

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Your comment should definitely be merged into the answer above! ;) Especially as it still leaves the "WHY?" part basically hanging. (The linked old "Future..." page also felt insufficient to me.)

(I know that I, too, could do it myself; one reason for hesitating is that I'd just be unable to *not* add something like "And as Kamil Maciorowski said in his comment...", which is kinda directly against the (anonymous) spirit of c. w. :) )

Comment: I've been a member of SE sites for a while, and recently became a lot more active. I really like how balanced and matured SE is nowadays, but Community Wiki is the one feature that doesn't seem well thought out. Seems like the only purpose is to remove rep, which maybe has its niche cases, but also sounds like kind of a screw-you to the author. In any case, there must be plenty of other features/benefits SE could add if they are serious about the feature, and documentation/presentation could be made more streamlined.

Comment: True, I was about to make something a community wiki, but I stopped.

Comment: Just like @ManoharReddyPoreddy I, too, was debating making an extensive answer into a community wiki, but then reading **this post basically "talked me out of it".**  (No advantage; only disadvantage.)  I would have *assumed* that the answer would at least have increased exposure to those looking for an answer covered within, but as far as I can tell it's still just based on the regular vote system.  Unfortunate if an answer was down-voted before substantial improvement (wiki or not) because it may never see the light of day...

Comment: Does the vote count of a community wiki question get reset (if it was originally downvoted)? - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/the-i-get-it-reputation-problem

Comment: From the last section of [The Future of Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) article it sounds to me like it should be used only when you (or even no one) can't provide a complete answer alone and want others to help you with this.

Comment: @Stephen how is it a screw-you to the author? You can just not do it if you want. i think it is good to have that option if that is what one wants.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 I have an answer with 1300+ upvotes, but it was marked Community Wiki at some point so I barely received any reputation for it. I did not mark it as such myself. Also, it has next to no edits by other users.

Comment: @aross I see. I did not realize someone could just switch it up like that. I agree with you then, seems like it needs more thinking through.

Comment: @aross: Excellent points from you and others here. I suggest you write a Meta post *"What are the reasons to not mark your answer “Community Wiki”"*? (and tie them to any existing enhance requests on SO, so we can lobby for them. Even knowing that many posters think CW is long-dead.)

Comment: Seems like many people are against "community wiki". Is it possible to vote for not using "community wiki" and stop using it if many people agree?

Comment: Check-marking the "community wiki" box seems like a bad idea for anyone answering a question subject to judgments based on emotion or spirituality, rather than physics or at least logic, especially with regard to subjects (notably cosmology) that tend to lack much potential for observational or experimental evidence.  I'd suppose that any check mark left by anyone acting contrary to the post's originator could be removed by that originator, although having to keep copies and checking serious posts seems like a possibility that might discourage prospective participants lacking the time for it.

Comment: In other words, the "Community Wiki" possibility seems as though it would discourage participation by professional physicists, as well as whatever postings they might have otherwise done with use of their real names.  Even worse, it could divert them away from posting on the site at all.  It really seems more like a play for a mass audience, and a potential magnet for advertisers. It also duplicates comments, which exist for suggestions for improvements and requests for clarification, and can be pinged to a question or answer's originator.

Comment: I'm not saying that this magnificent site, or its staffers, should lack funding, but I think that occasional Q's & A's by big names might be tried as an alternative means of pulling in marginal publicity or ad readers.  Surely they have some contractual means of avoiding situations like the one mentioned by aross on Feb. 27.

Comment: @KetZoomer please do not perform useless edits, that change nothing in a post, or don't make it even a bit better. It's an abuse of your edit privilege. Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating whoops, I didn't know I edited the question

Comment: As a counterpoint to the detractors: I mark my answers as a Community Wiki when they are based primarily on other people’s contributions. E.g., if the answer is based on the OP editing the answer into their question, another contributor posting the answer as a comment, a compilation of multiple incomplete answers, or an excerpt from an answer on another (non-duplicate) question. I see this as an administrative housekeeping task, and not something I should earn reputation for. In these cases, I give the author an opportunity to post their own answer, and delete the Community Wiki if they do.

Comment: @smci Reading this back again today, I'm considering doing it. Do you mean a new Meta question?

Comment: @aross: yes a self-answered question on Meta

Comment: It's nice to know you can contribute valuable information without fear of the downvotes affecting reputation. Of course, in order to avoid potential abuse, it's only fair that it also doesn't generate additional reputation either. How nice.

Comment: If you know you've got the expertise on a certain topic - and you also happen to have a sneaking suspicion that someone's gonna TOTALLY disagree with your factual evidence (which can cause a LOT of downvoting, no doubt), this is one way to make your stance known to everyone else without fear of being lost from lack of value. That, or some people know that the stuff they know can cause negative response from others, just saying.

Comment: How is vandalism handled? Can change be rolled back like in a Wikimedia fashion? Are there Talk pages or do the comments section play that role. Are community wiki answers inherently of lower or higher quality? Are they more exposed on searches?